# Does onclick work with any positioning?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I mage a cog symbol that is supposed to have an onclick function that triggers a function.  When I click it does not work.  Could it matter that it has absolute positioning?  How can I fix this?

I used this HTML:

```
<div id="cogdiv" onclick="theme()">
    <h1 id="cog" class="themechange fa fa-cog" onclick="theme()"></h1>
</div>
```

and this JS:

```
var theme = function() {
    document.getElementById('themes').style.animation = "themesappear 2s forwards";
    document.getElementById('themes').style.WebkitAnimation = "themesappear 2s forwards";
};
```

The function works when I run it in the console.

Inspect Element [here](https://caa8edf10c487b5ff2dc93e7192b6b4ab1ae15da-www.googledrive.com/host/0B-Yxt1Eo-wZVa05aNzM2alk3Rnc) for more code.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: It's best if you post your code in the actual question rather than an an external link which might disappear in the future. This is so the question will be useful to other people in the long-term future.

Comment: no it doesn't - it does matter thought if the element is being positioned behind another element which is blocking your mouse - check your z-index properties and if not try to add some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning has *no effect* on how the `onClick` event is being fired.

You are simply positioning your element below another element, so another element is *blocking the mouse event*

---

Try adding to your CSS:

```
#cogdiv {
 z-index: 9999; //or greater, or 1. Just make sure it's bigger than the overlapping element's z-index
}
```

Reading up on what [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and [CSS stack-order](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/) might also help.

Comment: That doesn't quite fix it yet. The OP has a different element on the page that's still covering the cog.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know that but I'm certainly not going to dive into explaining CSS document flow on this question:) - He knows what's going on now, if he wants to fix the root then that's another question

Comment: If you're not going to answer with a fix to his problem, then why bother answering at all? Your answer doesn't solve anything

Comment: I gave him the explanation of why the click event doesn't work and a quick fix. That was the question - Do I also have to design his page for him?

Comment: The quick fix doesn't do anything. It doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Hum, read the question again, see the code that he wants us to inspect - Add the z-index on the element and come back later if you want

Comment: The code in the question doesn't give _any_ clue that the z-index might be related to the issue... I did add the z-index on his site, but that doesn't solve the fact that there's a `position: absolute` div in front of the element, blocking click events.

Comment: Then feel free to sit down and provide an answer to that ;)

Comment: @Cerbrus Actually, it helped a lot.  He told me what the problem was.